# I change a single constant and the simple script suddenly takes forever to complete

Tags: graphics, programming, fractals

I writed a code to display the Dragon Curve fractal, and I reached my goal.
The algorithm works by taking the previous two points and then adding the following one by making a 90 degrees turn left or right. Even with 10 iterations the result appears almost instantaneously.

```
iterations = 2;
α = π/2;

ClearAll[seq, length];

(* Now I define the sequence. seq[3][[2]] = 1 means that at the 3rd
 iteration, the second curve will be clockwise; seq[3][[2]] = -1 means the
curve is counterclockwise *)

seq[0] = {};
For[n = 0, n < iterations, n++,
 seq[n + 1] = Join[seq[n], {1}, -Reverse[seq[n]]]
 ]

(* Rotation matrix: *)

rotm[x_] = {{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {-Sin[x], Cos[x]}};

n = iterations;

length = 2^n - 1;

(* First two points *)
pt[1] := {0, 0};
pt[2] := {1, 0};

(* Now I generate all the other points *)
For[i = 1, i <= length, i++,
 pt[i + 2] = 
   pt[i + 1] + rotm[Sign[seq[n][[i]]]*α].(pt[i + 1] - pt[i]);
 ]

curve = Table[pt[m], {m, 1, length + 2}];
Graphics[Line[curve], ImageSize -> 600]
```

Problems arise when I change the angle of the step (parameter $\alpha$ at the beginning of the code). If I set something like $\pi/4$ or $\pi/5$ the script takes forever even for one iteration of the algorithm (corresponding to a single new point...). If I set $\pi/3$ everything works fine and the result appears in a fraction of a second just like for the original $\pi/2$ turn. What is happening??

Comment: Works fine for me, Mathematica 10.2. By the way, a more natural definition of `seq` is `seq[n_] := seq[n] = Nest[Join[#, {1}, -Reverse@#] &, {}, n]` - since you only ever use `seq[iterations]`, this is sufficient, and much more readable. I also prefer `pt[1] = {0, 0}; pt[2] = {1, 0}; pt[i_] := 
 pt[i] = pt[i - 1] + 
   RotationMatrix[
     seq[iterations][[i - 2]]*\[Alpha]].(pt[i - 1] - pt[i - 2])` as a definition of `pt`, because it is again clearer what it's doing.

Comment: Fascinating - when I set it to pi/5, it slowed down a bit, but then the kernel crashed when I tried to evaluate `DownValues[pt]`. There is more to it than I first thought. EDIT: belisarius is right, of course.

Comment: @PatrickStevens [Wanna clarity?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9351/315) :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I set

```
iterations = 3;
α = π/5;
```

and run your program and then execute

```
curve // LeafCount
```

I get

```
(* 15649 *)
```

The problem is that you should compute numerical (not exact) results 
Just replace:

```
rotm[x_] := N@{{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {-Sin[x], Cos[x]}}}
```

and it runs

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much. This solved everything.